# Copy failed records to dynamo db

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb

I am copying 50 million records to amazon dynamodb using hive script. The script failed after running for 2 days with an item size exceeded exception.

Now if I restart the script again, it will start the insertions again from first record. Is there a way where I can say like "Insert only those records which are not in dynamo db" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional writes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate) to only write the item if it the specified attributes are not equal to the values you provide. This is done by using the [`ConditionExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ConditionExpression) for a `PutItem` request. However, [it still uses write capacity even if a write fails](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ConditionExpression) (emphasis mine) so this may not even be the best option for you:

> **If a ConditionExpression fails during a conditional write, DynamoDB
>   will still consume one write capacity unit from the table.** A failed
>   conditional write will return a ConditionalCheckFailedException
>   instead of the expected response from the write operation. For this
>   reason, you will not receive any information about the write capacity
>   unit that was consumed. However, you can view the
>   ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits metric for the table in Amazon CloudWatch
>   to determine the provisioned write capacity that was consumed from the
>   table.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using hive script to insert the records. I am not sure how can I use conditional writes in that case.